# Why is this authentication protocol with a nonce and tree parties not secure?

Tags: authentication, symmetric

Why is the following authentication service not secure?

C⟶S: $I_C$

S⟶C: $N$

C⟶S: $E(K_{C,A}, N)$

S⟶A: $E(K_{S,A}, \{I_C, E(K_{C,A}, N)\})$

A⟶S: $E(K_{S,A}, N)$

where:

- C = client
- S = server
- A = authentication service
- $I_X$ = identification string of entity X
- $N$ is nonce
- $E(K, M)$ is the encryption operation using key $K$ and message $M$
- $K_{X,Y}$ = symmetric key shared by X and Y

Comment: What is the operation denoted by Key(message)? Encryption? MAC?

Comment: This protocol is vulnerable to replay attack.

Comment: This is clearly an assignment, what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @MeysamGhahramani That's an answer, not a comment. We expect answers to be substantiated. It's nice to see that you seem to know the answer, but like this it is not useful to anybody. There seems to be a nonce, so some reason why this doesn't protect the protocol from replay attack is needed here.

Comment: @Maeher it's an encryption operation.

Comment: sorry if I was not clear.
I want to know why the authentication between client and server could go wrong.

Comment: You are basically trying to use the fact that you can produce a ciphertext of $N$ under a certain key to prove that you know the key. But in general nothing about the security of an encryption scheme implies that I cannot produce valid ciphertexts without the key.

Comment: How can I produce a valid nonce cipher if I do not know the key of C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the client and server were once connected by random number $N$, and adversary is eavesdropped these messages. So he has $I_C$, $N$, $E(K_{C,A}, N)$, $E(K_{S,A}, \{I_C, E(K_{C,A}, N)\})$ and $E(K_{S,A}, N)$. Now in the new session, the adversary can easily impersonate the identity of the server. To do so, just follow the steps below:

C⟶Adversary: $I_C$

Adversary⟶C: $N$

C⟶Adversary: $E(K_{C,A}, N)$

Adversary⟶A: $E(K_{S,A}, \{I_C, E(K_{C,A}, N)\})$

A⟶Adversary: $E(K_{S,A}, N)$

Note that in this protocol, the server can use $E(K_{S,A}, N)$ to verify client identity, but the client does not have any information about the identity of the server.

**Edit:** Also, an adversary cannot impersonate the client using $E(K_{C,A},N)$ because $N$ is generated by a valid server and will change in each session. Therefore, an adversary cannot find the valid $E(K_{C,A},N)$ using previous eavesdropped messages. To prevent this attack, you can modify the protocol as follows:

C⟶S: $I_C$

S⟶C: $N$

C⟶S: $E(K_{C,A}, N, M)$

S⟶A: $E(K_{S,A}, \{I_C, E(K_{C,A}, N, M)\})$

A⟶S: $E(K_{S,A}, N, E(K_{C,A}, M))$

S⟶C: $E(K_{C,A}, M)$

However, this is just a change, and the resistance of this protocol to other attacks should be investigated. "Cryptographic Protocol: Security Analysis Based on Trusted Freshness" By Ling Dong and Kefei Chen, is a valuable book on protocols that you can refer to for more information.

Comment: what kind of change would you propose to solve the problem?

Comment: an adversary could also impers the client using E(KC,A,N)?

Comment: is there a possibility of an MITM attack? the adversary intercept  E(KC,A,N) and send it to the server pretending to be the client

Comment: @rokmiefran, This is possible for all protocols but not as an attack. Because the attacker acts as a communication channel that delivers only the sender's message to the recipient and does not receive any information.